# How to upload ftp directory using ruby

Tags: ruby, ftp

I need to upload a directory having sub-directories to a ftp server.

I can upload a file using

```
require 'net/ftp'
ftp = Net::FTP.new(options[:remote_host])
ftp.login(options[:username], options[:password])

ftp.put(File.open("filename"))

ftp.quit
```

It fails with uploading directory receiving error...

```
Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory
```

Can anyone give help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Net::FTP` implements [FTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and *FTP* uses `MKD` command to create directories (different from commands used to create files). `Net::FTP` can create directory with special [Net::FTP#mkdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-mkdir) method.

> **mkdir(dirname)**
>
> Creates a remote directory.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create the sub-directories and upload the files 'manually'.
Every FTP client do it this way.